# Creating a jQuery container to hold other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a simple class or a container to hold few JavaScript methods as shown below.

```
var Core = (function () {

    var Error = {
        alert: function() {
            alert('Error => alert called');
        },
        display: function() {
            alert('Error => display called');
        }
    };

    var ajax = {
        view: function(){
            alert('Ajax => view called');
        },
        update: function(){
            alert('Ajax => update called');
        }
    };

    var call = function(){
        Error.alert();
        Error.display();
        ajax.view();
        ajax.update();
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
       call(); // This works fine.
    }());
```

But for some reason I am not able to call these methods outside the container. For instance calling functions as shown below throws error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Core.Error.alert(); // This doesn't work.
    Core.Call(); // This doesn't work.

});
```

**Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Error' of undefined**

I can call the functions from within the container. I am new to the concept of jQuery plugins and would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Error, ajax, call are private variables/functions and not properties of Core.

Comment: Tiny note: you have some unused `()` at the end of your DOM ready handler function. That one is not an IIFE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export these methods (read more about [`Module Pattern`](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)), like so

```
var Core = (function () {
  ...

  return {
    Error: Error,
    Ajax: ajax,
    Call: call
  };
})();

Core.Error.alert();
Core.Call();
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/vozexujopu/1/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 2):

Change it in:

```
var Core = {     
    error: {
        alert: function () {
            alert('Error => alert called');
        },
        display: function () {
            alert('Error => display called');
        }
    }, 

    ajax: {
        view: function () {
            alert('Ajax => view called');
        },
        update: function () {
            alert('Ajax => update called');
        }
    }, 

    call: function () {
        Core.error.alert();
        Core.error.display();
        Core.ajax.view();
        Core.ajax.update();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    Core.call(); // This works
}());
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLspetmj/1/)

Comment: You seems to have some extra closing `()` inside the end of the DOM ready handler (ah, as did the OP).